# How to use multiple condition in 'when'

Tags: ansible

I have a Windows services start/stop playbook and services are specific to certain hosts.

I want to control start/stop services if it exists in a specific host.

I have a `when` to run on specific hosts but how to add and clause to check if services `fromAppStopServices.yml` exists before start or stop ?

Sample code

```yaml
    -name: service stop
    hosts:all

    tasks:
    -name: Include app services
     include_vars:
         file: inventory/{{ env }}/group_vars/appstopservice.syml
    -name: stop app services
     win_service:
       name: "{[ item }}"
       state: stopped
     loop: "{{ services }}"
     when: inventory_hostname in group['Appservers']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [win_service_info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_service_info_module.html) module to get the list of all win services on the target server, register the output and then query it to see if the service already exists before stopping it.

```yaml
---

- name: service stop
  hosts: all

  tasks:
  - name: Include app services
    include_vars:
      file: inventory/{{ env }}/group_vars/appstopservice.syml

#  #Option 1 - using ansible win_service_info module
#  - name: Get info for all installed services
#    win_service_info:
#    register: service_info

  # Option2 - using ansible powershell module
  - name: Get info for all installed services
    win_powershell:
      script: Get-Service
    register: service_info

#  # Option3 - using ansible win_shell module
#  - name: Get info for all installed services
#    win_shell: | 
#      sc queryex type=service state=all
#    args:
#      executable: cmd
#    register: service_info

  - name: stop app services
    win_service:
      name: "{[ item }}"
      state: stopped
      loop: "{{ services }}"
    when: 
      - inventory_hostname in group['Appservers']
      - service_info.stdout.find(item) != -1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that and found out that win_service_info module has not been installed and need to request separately which would months before it is available.  Is there any other way to find the existence of the service before stop/start

Comment: That's strange, as both win_service_info and win_service are part of the same collection.  Can you share the logs ? 
You could also install the collection using "ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.windows" command. See the note "https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_service_info_module.html#ansible-windows-win-service-info-module-gather-information-about-windows-services" for more details

Comment: Error message I got is as follows.   ERROR: Could not resolve module/action "ansible.windows.win_service_info". This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path".      In my company ansible module collection, this does not exist and it would take for me to get it installed. Any other way to verify ?

Comment: Other option is to use the "win_powershell" or "win_shell" to query the list of services on the target host. Do you have these modules installed ?

Comment: I have updated the answer with extra options. Please try this out, as I don't have a local windows environment to test this.

Comment: Same issue with win_powershell module. It is not present in our libraries but i could use win_shell module. I get an error though.  "The error while evaluating conditional (service_info.find(item) != -1) 'dict_object' has no attribute find '

Comment: Ah ! my mistake. Instead of querying the full output, we should be querying the stdout of service_info var. I have updated the answer. Try this and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @AnandIyer: how did it go ? Did you get a chance to test this ?